# How to extract selected attribute(s) from an NSArray of Core Data entity objects and form into a joint string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsstring, nsarray

Normally, if I have an NSArray of just NSString's, I can use the NSArray's method:

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

to get a String (like "John,David,Peter"). However, if I have an NSArray of Core Data Entity objects and I just need to to get 1 attribute within (say, the "name" attribute only of each entity object), what is the easiest way to do this?

The Core Data entity object can have many attributes (name, phone, birthdate), but I just want a string like "John,David,Peter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do a fetch for only the `name` properties of the `Person` objects:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"name"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSString *names = [[array valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@", names);
```

You need to set the `resultType` to `NSDictionaryResultType` otherwise it will ignore `propertiesToFetch`. The result from the fetch is an array of Dictionaries. Using `valueForKey` and `componentsJoinedByString` will create a single string out of all the names.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is the straightforward one of building up a NSMutableString by iterating over the items in you array and asking each one for its name to use in `appendString:`.  You could add a `description` method to the entity object and then use the method you mentioned but `description` is used for other things and would probably cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming you have the list of entities - NSArray *entityObjects 
NSMutableString *nameAttributes = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < [entityObjects count]-1; i++){
    [nameAttributes appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", [entityObjects objectAtIndex:i].name]];
}
    [nameAttributes appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [entityObjects lastObject].name]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `NSArray *objects` of Core Data objects, each of which has a `name` attribute, then you can use

```
NSArray *names = [objects valueForKey:@"name"];
```

to get a new array with all the names, which you can then concatenate with

```
NSString *allNames = [names componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like that,

```
NSString *toCollectString =@"";

for(int k =0;k<self.arrayHoldingObjects.count;k++)
{
   ModelName *model = [self.arrayHoldingObjects objectAtIndex:k];  
   NSString *str = model.name;
   toCollectString = [toCollectString stringByAppendingString:str];  
}
```

You will get the names in `toCollectString`.